# Radio button and messages

Tags: python, radio-button, tkinter, message

How can I make that when radio button is checked that then it shows some message(in Python 3 and Tkinter)?

for example:

```
from Tkinter import *

master = Tk()

v = IntVar()

Radiobutton(master, text="One", variable=v, value=1).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Two", variable=v, value=2).pack(anchor=W)

mainloop()
```

and when one of buttons is checked that then it shows some message, for ex. "RadioButton1 is checked"

Comment: Please give more information and code exemple to see the context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the command option for tkinters Checkbutton...

```
from tkinter import *

class Application(Frame):
    def say_hi(self):
        if self.var.get() or self.var2.get():
            msg = ''
            if self.var.get():
                msg = 'Radio button 1 is checked\n'
            if self.var2.get():
                msg += 'Radio button 2 is checked'

            print(msg) # to sdtout...
            top = Toplevel()
            top.title("Pop-up...")
            msg = Message(top, text=msg)
            msg.pack()
            button = Button(top, text="Close", command=top.destroy)
            button.pack()

    def createWidgets(self):
        self.QUIT = Button(self)
        self.QUIT["text"] = "Close"
        self.QUIT["fg"]   = "red"
        self.QUIT["command"] =  self.quit
        self.QUIT.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.var = IntVar()
        self.checkbox = Checkbutton(self)
        self.checkbox["text"] = 'radio1'
        self.checkbox["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.checkbox["variable"] = self.var
        self.checkbox.pack({"side": "left"})

        self.var2 = IntVar()
        self.checkbox2 = Checkbutton(self)
        self.checkbox2["text"] = 'radio2'
        self.checkbox2["command"] = self.say_hi
        self.checkbox2["variable"] = self.var2
        self.checkbox2.pack({"side": "left"})

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.pack()
        self.createWidgets()

root = Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

When a Radiobutton is selected, the function used in the `command` option is called (if present). Remember to pass a reference to the event handler function, that is, the name of the function without parentheses.

```
def handler():
    print "RadioButton%s is checked" % (v.get())

Radiobutton(master, text="One", variable=v, value=1, command=handler).pack(anchor=W)
Radiobutton(master, text="Two", variable=v, value=2, command=handler).pack(anchor=W)
```